# PHP $_SESSION returning incorrect value

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

Ok, so when I execute the initial function it works fine, the username gets stored in the database, however when I run the second function that appends the username to the text the user chooses to enter the IF statement returns 'no user' - when a user is defined...

If anyone knows how to fix this that would be great - I am currently learning PHP and mysql so I am sorry if any of this is incorrect

```
<?php

session_start()

    // connect to the database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("ajaxchat");



    // read the stage

    $stage = $_POST['stage'];

    // primary code
    if($stage == 'initial') {

        // check the username       
        $user = $_POST['user'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat_active WHERE user='$user'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {

            $time = time();

            // 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO chat_active VALUES ('$user', '$time')");

            // set the session
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;

            echo 'good';
        }
        else {
            echo 'taken';
        }
    }

/////////////// PROBLEM FUNCTION ///////////////
================================================

    else if($stage == 'send') {
        // get the textdomain
        $text = $_POST['text'];

        // check for user_error
        if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
            $user = $_SESSION['user'];
            echo $user.' - '.$text.'<br />';
        }
        else {
            echo 'no user';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'error';
    }
?>
```

## This is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chat_initialise() {
        var user = document.getElementById("chat_user").value;

        $.post("./chat.php", {stage:"initial", user:user}, function(data) {
            if (data == "good") {
                $('#initial').css('display', 'none');
                $('#content').css('display', 'inline')
            }
            else {
                alert("That username is taken! Please try another.");
            }
        });
    }

    function chat_send() {
        var text = document.getElementById("chat_text").value;

        $.post("./chat.php", {stage:"send", text:text}, function(data) {
            document.getElementById("chat_text").value = '';
            $('#window').text($('#window').text() + data);
            // alert(data)
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get the output: `good` ?

Comment: yes - http://gyazo.com/1933a147f866a4e057b3d48d06353abd @Rizier123

Comment: Try reversing these `$user = $_SESSION['user'];` like you did for the other one. `$_SESSION['user'] = $user;`

Comment: But if I did that I would be over-writing the stored 'user' variable with a blank one? that bit is trying to get the username from the table in the database @Fred-ii-

Also that still gives the response: no user

Comment: Obligatory comment 1) you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and 2) don't use the `mysql_` extension : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: @cookies Since you say you get: `no user` as output. Also add a `var_dump($_SESSION);` right under this echo statement (e.g. `else {
            echo 'no user'; var_dump($_SESSION);
        }`) and show us the output

Comment: @Rizier123 http://gyazo.com/ab4d31b3c1221e9c680936c61b313996

Comment: Do you have a `session_destroy()` or a `session_unset()` somewhere after this code ? And check if SESSION is enabled.

Comment: @CD001 - I know its really poor programming and yes it would be very easy to attack, but I have literally just start php, thanks for the link - I shall have a look

Comment: @Spoke44 no, the only php code is the code I put above. How would I check if sessions are active?

Comment: `else if($stage == 'send') {` might be failing and is related to your POST in your form as per `$stage = $_POST['stage'];` which you should probably show us what it looks like. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Your error reads *Undefined variable _SESSION* which tends to imply as @Spoke44 says, the session has been destroyed (or not started properly) otherwise the `$_SESSION` superglobal *should* exist. It also looks like you're doing this with AJAX so is this the script that's being called by AJAX? If not, does the script that's being called also have a `session_start()` call?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added that section of code and this was the result. http://gyazo.com/f18f5889981983f7f424f62a37d39367

Comment: I don't know if it helps but I have added the js that calls the functions

Comment: *Undefined variable `_SESSION`* - Huh? This tells me your session variable is broken and/or malformed. Something related to your Ajax maybe. You need to show us more related code. This commenting back and forth is going nowhere fast.

Comment: should:
$.post("./chat.php", {stage:"send", text:text}, function(data)

become:
$.post("./chat.php", {stage:"send", text:text, user:user}, function(data)

?

Comment: @cookies My last advice here on this question: You got some really good people in the comments which are trying to help you! But that they are able to help, you have to show your **full** and **real** code! Also as already said add error reporting at the top of your file **(s)** (`<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`) and tell us every error you get! Also consider to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Rizier123 Oh, the last time I posted my entire source code I was told that wasn't the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it - changed the POST function to take the current username then redefine it as a variable in the second function:

```
else if($stage == 'send') {
    // get the textdomain
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];

    echo $user;

    // check for user_error
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        echo $user.' - '.$text.'<br />';
    }
    else {
        echo 'no user';
        var_dump($_SESSION);
    }
}
```

Thanks for all your help guys!!

Comment: Glad to know you've found your own solution, *cheers* and you're welcome ;-)

Comment: Essentially bypassing the session entirely by sending the user through again with the second AJAX call ... that's one way around it; I've still got this weird niggly feeling that you're losing your session here somewhere though ;)

Comment: @CD001 I'm sure it will break something else in the near future haha! I honestly don't know where it could be losing my session as the php in the question is literally the entire php script

Comment: yes you done that but it's not the correct way to use session and there is no user in chat_send function then how you can access the value of user in else if send part ?